# How to use a function result in another function with async await

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have have a function that should be run if another function return is true:

```
// in utils.js
methods:{
  funcOne(){
    // do some thing
    return true
  }
}


//in component.vue
methods:{
  funcTwo(){
    let x = this.funcOne()
    if(x){
    // do something
    }else{
    // do something
    }
  }
}
```

how can i do this? as js is runtime it won't wait for result of `funcOne()` and i know i should be using `Promise` or `async/await`. but dont know how!!

**UPDATE**

i did as suggested but still not working so gonna explain the situation :
i'm using `sweet alert`. if my `sweet alert` is confirmed it should send an axios request. here is the code:

utils.js is a globally added mixins

```
async function sweetAlert(options) {
  // options: method('callback') , icon, title, text, callback, cValue
  if (options.method === 'confirm' || options.method === 'callback') {
    this.$swal({
      icon: options.icon,
      title: options.title,
      text: options.text,
      showCancelButton: true,
      cancelButtonText: this.lang.cancel,
      confirmButtonText: this.lang.confirm
    }).then(async (result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        if (options.method === 'callback') {
          let res = await options.callback(options.cValue)
          return res
        }

        return true
      }
    })
  }
}
```

my component script:

```
let res = await this.sweetAlert({
  method: ALERT_METHOD[2], // it is 'confirm'
  icon: ALERT_TYPE[2], // it is warning
  title: this.lang.deactivate, // added globally
  text: this.lang.deactivate_warning, // added globally
})

if (res) {
  this.activeSwitchDis = true // in my data
  this.activeChanged = true // in my data
  // this.axiosGet is a globally adde this.axios.get
  let response = await this.axiosGet(`product/deactive/${this.editProduct.pId}`)
  // this.resOk is globally added and check for 200
  if (this.resOk(response.status)) {
    // these are my data and funcs no prob with theme
    this.changeError(false)
    this.active = false
    this.activeChanged = false
    this.activeSwitchDis = false
    this.setEditProductActive(this.active)
  } else {
    // these are my data and funcs no prob with theme
    this.active = true
    this.activeChanged = false
    this.activeSwitchDis = false
  }
}
```

the problem is only that the axios must be run if i confirm the sweetAlert

Comment: funcOne *isn't* an async function, and it doesn't seem to return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as js is runtime it won't wait for result of `funcOne()`

Since the `funcOne()` *in your example* code is not an async function this is not correct: the call *will* wait for the function to complete and return its value.

> how can i do this? [...] and i know i should be using Promise or `async/await`. but dont know how!!

Then it is probably best for you to read on [the documentation for Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and [the `async/await` Syntax for functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) since you need a proper understanding of them to use it effectively.

### Update

Now to your actual code: your implementation of `sweetAlert()` does not actually return *anything* because the `return`s are scoped to another function:

```js
# abbreviated code:
async function sweetAlert(options) {
  if (...) {
    this.$swal({...}).then(async (result) => {
      if (...) {
        let res = await options.callback(options.cValue)
        return res
      }

      return true
    })
  }
}
```

So the `return res` and `return true` are actually scoped to the function which is passed to the `then()` handler. This chain will return another promise which will resolve with the value of that `return`s. To catch this as the return value of `sweetAlert()` you need to `return` it:

```js
# abbreviated code:
function sweetAlert(options) {
  if (...) {
    // return the result of the chain here for sweetAlert()
    return this.$swal({...}).then(async (result) => {
      if (...) {
        let res = await options.callback(options.cValue)
        return res
      }

      return true
    })
  }
}
```

Note that `sweetAlert()` will only return something if it enters the first `if` block. Also note that you don't use `await` in the `sweetAlert()` functions (but only in other functions within it) and return a `Promise` and not a raw value you can omit the `async` keyword for it.

Alternatively you can go the full way with `async/await`:

```js
async function sweetAlert(options) {
  if (options.method === 'confirm' || options.method === 'callback') {
    // await the return value here
    let result = await this.$swal({...})

    if (result.value) {
      if (options.method === 'callback') {
        let res = await options.callback(options.cValue)
        return res
      }

      // now this will return from sweetAlert()
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i did as told, but no result, so updated my issue with actual code. plz help

Answer (score 1):

```
methods:{
  async funcOne(){
    // do some thing
    await someAsyncFunctionOrLogic();
    return true
  }
}


//in component.vue
methods:{
  async funcTwo(){
    let x = await this.funcOne()
    if(x){
    // do something
    }else{
    // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i did as u said but no result, so updated with my actual code. plz help